# Coredata working with data (Multithreading)

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data, mapkit

I need to place hotspots to the Map. All of them are saved with CoreData (it's about 25000).
So I need 25000 annotations. I also implement MKAnnotation protocol for HotSpot Entity.

Selected solution for this situation was multithreading. But after pins are on the map some of them has no data (data ).

here is code that populate data in array

```
- (void)addAnnotationsForCurrentLocation {
    NSInteger hotSpotsCount = [HotSpot MR_countOfEntities];
    self.testSpotsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:hotSpotsCount];
    NSInteger lastThread;
    NSInteger threads = 5;
    //calculate how much spots will be in the 
    NSInteger spotsInThread = hotSpotsCount/threads;
    //calclulate how mush threads will be in one spot
    lastThread = hotSpotsCount - spotsInThread*(threads-1);
    dispatch_queue_t firstThreadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.thecloud.firstThreadQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
    dispatch_queue_t secondThreadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.thecloud.secondThreadQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
    dispatch_queue_t thirdThreadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.thecloud.thirdThreadQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
    dispatch_queue_t forthThreadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.thecloud.forthThreadQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
    dispatch_queue_t fifthThreadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.thecloud.fifthThreadQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);

    dispatch_group_t fillArrayGroup = dispatch_group_create();
    NSLock *arrayLock = [[NSLock alloc] init];

    dispatch_group_async(fillArrayGroup, firstThreadQueue, ^{
        [self fetchWithOffest:0 andLimit:spotsInThread andLock:arrayLock];
        DDLogInfo(@"com.thecloud.firstThreadQueue and self.testSpotsArray objects - %i", [self.testSpotsArray count]);
    });

    //Other Queue

    dispatch_group_notify(fillArrayGroup, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.treeController setAnnotations:self.testSpotsArray];
    });

    dispatch_release(fillArrayGroup);
}
- (void)fetchWithOffest:(NSInteger)offset andLimit:(NSInteger)limit andLock:(NSLock *)arrayLock {
    NSFetchRequest *request = [HotSpot MR_requestAll];
    [request setFetchOffset:offset];
    [request setFetchLimit:limit];
    [request setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
    NSArray *array = [HotSpot MR_executeFetchRequest:request];
    for (int i=0; i < [array count]; i++) {
        HotSpot *spot = (HotSpot *)[array objectAtIndex:i];
        [spot convertLogitudeAndLattitudeToLocationCoordinate];
        [arrayLock lock];
        [self.testSpotsArray addObject:spot];
        [arrayLock unlock];
    }
}
```

After this when I tap on some of pins no popup with description appears.
Any solution to have full data in each object in the array of annotations?

**UPD**

Problem solved. I did change in my entity model. Now when I add the entity to annotations array instead of

```
-(NSString *)title {
    return self.title;
}

-(NSString *)subtitle {
    return self.spotToAddress.addressLine1;
}

-(CLLocationCoordinate2D) coordinate {
    return CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([self.latitude doubleValue], [self.longitude doubleValue]);
}
```

I use direct assignment

```
- (void)prepareAnnotation {
    _title = self.name;
    _subtitle = self.spotToAddress.addressLine1;
    _coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([self.latitude doubleValue], [self.longitude doubleValue]);
}
```

Comment: Looks like your problem was the title method. `-(NSString *)title {
    return self.title;
}` will cause an infinite loop as `self.title` calls the method it is being called from.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I did change in my entity model. Now when I add the entity to annotations array instead of

```
-(NSString *)title {
    return self.title;
}

-(NSString *)subtitle {
    return self.spotToAddress.addressLine1;
}

-(CLLocationCoordinate2D) coordinate {
    return CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([self.latitude doubleValue], [self.longitude doubleValue]);
}
```

I use direct assignment

```
- (void)prepareAnnotation {
    _title = self.name;
    _subtitle = self.spotToAddress.addressLine1;
    _coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([self.latitude doubleValue], [self.longitude doubleValue]);
}
```